# Vue.js: toggle hamburger menu icons

Tags: javascript, vue.js, toggle, hamburger-menu

I have a header with a hamburger menu icon which I want to change to a cross icon when I click on this. How to do this in the Vue template? I created a function in the computed property but I am not sure what I should do.

Here is my menu icon:

```
<div class="top-icon" :class="toggleTopMenu" @click="showTopMenu = !showTopMenu">
  <div class="main-item menu">
    <span class="line line01"></span>
    <span class="line line02"></span>
    <span class="line line03"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.top-icon {
  background: #29afd1;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 500px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.28, 1.54) 0.32s;
}

.line01 {
  top: 19%;
}

.line02 {
  top: 49%;
}

.line03 {
  top: 79%;
}

.menu.close .line01 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 49%;
}

.menu.close .line02, .menu.close .line03 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 49%;
}
```

So far, this is what I have inside script tags:

```
data() {
  return {
    showTopMenu: false,
  };
},
computed: {
toggleTopMenu() {},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean this kind of implementation?
I just added `v-if` and `v-else` on your code

Please check the snippet below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    showTopMenu: false,
  }
})
```

```css
.top-icon {
  background: #29afd1;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 500px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.28, 1.54) 0.32s;
}

.line01 {
  top: 19%;
}

.line02 {
  top: 49%;
}

.line03 {
  top: 79%;
}

.menu.close .line01 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 49%;
}

.menu.close .line02, .menu.close .line03 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 49%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="top-icon" class="toggleTopMenu" @click="showTopMenu = !showTopMenu">
    <div class="main-item menu" v-if="!showTopMenu">
      <span class="line line01"></span>
      <span class="line line02"></span>
      <span class="line line03"></span>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      X
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I apologize about the UI though. :)

Comment: Seems like it is a solution but what should I put inside `<div v-else>`?

Comment: The X or Cross icon it seems.

Comment: Yes, I understand but I don't get how I will animate this. I mean if I put inside this div the same code than nothing will change. I need to animate this with a click. See this example please: https://codepen.io/jenningscreate/pen/xrbxKZ  In this example jQuery was used but I don't know how to implement the same behaviour in my Vue template.

Comment: @OlgaB the animation in codepen.io/jenningscreate/pen/xrbxKZ is based on purely CSS. jQuery was only used to add/remove class there, which you can easily do in Vue as well. I converted the example to Vue in https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/QQoJYX . You may try it. It's mainly about CSS here. Not about Javascript or Vue.

Comment: @JacobGoh thank you very much! This is what I wanted.

Comment: @OlgaB would you mind giving my answer a vote for correct impl? hehe